# calling code behind sub from dynamic button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I am generating a dynamic button with the following code:

```
Dim btn As New Button()
btn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
btn.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "btnCreate_Click()")
```

I have the button showing and trying to call the following sub:

```
Protected Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("https:\\www.google.com", False)
End Sub
```

The thing is even when I debug code never gets into the sub.

How can I call a code behind from Dynamically generated button?

Edit:

if this is going to be helpful the button sits in asp:table

```
tableCellButton.Controls.Add(btn)
...
table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellButton)
...
inbox_table.Rows.Add(table_row)
```

Complete Code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DisplayTable()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayTable()

    If member_id Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

        Dim dbContext As New *Hidden*
        Dim inbox = From p In dbContext.Inboxes Where p.RecordId = member_id Select p
        Dim inboxList As IEnumerable(Of *Hidden*) = inbox.ToList()

        If inboxList.Count < 1 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For Each i In inboxList

            Dim table_row As TableRow = New TableRow()

            Dim tableCellInboxId As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim tableCellRecordId As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim tableCellMemberId As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim tableCellImportance As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim tableCellReceivedFrom As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim tableCellReceivedSubject As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim tableCellReceivedDateTime As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim tableCellReceivedBody As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim tableCellButton As TableCell = New TableCell()

            ' Dynamic Button
            Dim btn As New Button
            btn.Text = "Click Me"
            btn.ID = "ClickMeID"

            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnCreate_Click

            tableCellInboxId.Text = i.InboxId.ToString
            tableCellRecordId.Text = i.RecordId.ToString
            tableCellMemberId.Text = i.MemberId.ToString
            tableCellImportance.Text = i.Importance.ToString
            tableCellReceivedFrom.Text = i.ReceivedFrom.ToString
            tableCellReceivedSubject.Text = i.ReceivedSubject.ToString
            tableCellReceivedDateTime.Text = i.ReceivedDateTime.ToString
            tableCellReceivedBody.Text = i.ReceivedBody.ToString
            tableCellButton.Controls.Add(btn)

            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellInboxId)
            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellRecordId)
            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellMemberId)
            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellImportance)
            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellReceivedFrom)
            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellReceivedSubject)
            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellReceivedDateTime)
            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellReceivedBody)
            table_row.Cells.Add(tableCellButton)

            inbox_table.Rows.Add(table_row)

        Next

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    If btn.ID = "ClickMeID" Then
        'Response.Redirect(blablabla)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

`AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnCreate_Click` should wire up the event handler server side.  I don't think you need the two attributes you are setting.  You also need to add the button inside the form for the page.

Here is an example using the default WebForms template in VS2013, which uses master pages.

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    ' Note: This also seems to work from Page_Load

    Dim button = New Button()
    button.Text = "Click Me"
    ' MainContent is the ContentPlaceHolderID of the content control in the master page
    Me.Master.FindControl("MainContent").Controls.Add(button)
    AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf MyButton_Clicked

End Sub

Protected Sub MyButton_Clicked(sender As Object, a As EventArgs)
    Debug.Print("Clicked!")
End Sub
```

Comment: I added the following code  `Dim btn As New Button()
                      btn.Text = "Click Me"
                      AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnCreate_Click`                                          but that does not do anything.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some additional details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
 Dim btn As New Button
 btn.Text = "Click Me"
 btn.ID = "btnClickMe"
 AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnCreate_Click
End Sub

Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
 Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
 If btn.ID = "btnClickMe" Then
   Response.Redirect(blablabla)
 End If
End Sub
```

I give you simple example, you can do everything what you want to do after first line in new sub.
Just, like someone wrote here, You don't need those attributes.
You can create multiply buttons and in btnCreate_Click sub manage them and, in your case, do redirect to page(s).
btw. best way is to create those buttons in Page_Init.
Hope I help you.

other example :

```
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
 For x = 1 To 3
  Dim btn As New Button
  btn.Text = "Button #" + x.ToString()
  btn.ID = "btn" + x.ToString()
  AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnCreate_Click
 Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
 Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
 If btn.ID = "btn1" Then
   Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com")
 ElseIf btn.ID = "btn2" Then
   Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com")
 Else 'this is btn3
   Response.Redirect("http://www.facebook.com")
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @nelek I put a break point on the `Private Sub btnCreate_Click ...` the code does not even get to that sub. I have it exactly what you typed in. The button is displayed on the page but something is not hooked up to it. When I click on it it just does a postBack.

Comment: I hope so you changed that "blablabla" in response.redirect with some address.
Remove attributes.

Comment: The code NEVER gets INTO the SUB i am debugging but have no idea how to find out what is not working.

Comment: btw. if your aspx filename is not Default.aspx then Page_Init must be replaced with youraspxfilename_Init. Example: if your aspx filename is mytables.aspx then it must be mytables_Init... btw. this perfectly working to me. Try one of codes in blank new project.

Comment: Inside a Page_Load() I am calling a private sub to build a table. That button goes inside a table. It displays correctly how I want it but when I click on it - suppose to call a Protected sub in code behind. I am not using Page_Init at all (whatever the default functionality is there I have not made any modifications to it). I am getting an error "Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: undefined"

Comment: move your code from _load to _init subroutine. for dynamically creating table and buttons. and change from protected to private.

Comment: I tried it just for testing. Moved just a button to init. The button is displayed correctly when I click on it, however it does a post back and the sub still NOT being called and I get the same error Error In event handler. It shouldn't really matter when that button is by the time page is displayed it is loaded.

Comment: button and that code for table creating... or just call sub for table creating from _init sub.

Comment: Just the button code. I am not even displaying the table now.

Comment: can you place your code here (page_load, sub for creating table, and sub for dynamically created button)?

Comment: Updated the original comment.

Comment: how do you add that button, or where? if you just try to add button then you need one line more after addhandler... form1.Controls.Add(btn)

Comment: I have <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpPage" runat="server"> inside there that is where the table sits. I think that placeholder is wrapped inside a form but that is in a parent page.

Comment: I think there is error : btn.ID = "ClickMeID"... ID must be unique ... try btn.ID = "ClickMeID" + i.InboxId.ToString ... but then in btnCreate_Click sub you must put so many if...elseif...else...end if... placehold isn't problem... just question, I think is better solution to put <a href... instead buttons there... did all of this buttons redirect to same page (in this example: http://www.google.com) ?

Comment: The thing is even though the IDs are different NOW STILL IT NEVER GETS INSIDE the SUB. The event is wrong, not wired correctly.

Comment: If purpose of buttons to redirect to same page, remove btn.id while creating and in btnCreate_Click remove If btn.ID row, use just redirect... If every button redirect to some other pages then do next:
while creating buttons, remove btn.ID, put btn.CommandArgument="xx" (xx = webaddr from ur db, i suppose) and in btnCreate_Click sub remove If btn.ID too but put response.redirect(btn.CommandArgument.ToString,False)... Is helpful this? In both cases you don't need btn.ID (but, If you ever use ID, ID must be unique, like I wrote prev.post)

Comment: from where are you create this table and buttons? from master in content? or from content page?

Comment: Dim btn As New Button
                btn.Text = "Click Me"
                btn.CommandArgument = "https:\\www.google.com\"
              added this code and this does not redirect anywhere just does a postback to the same page

Comment: can I send you example on some mail to try it?

Comment: I just created an empty project and tried this and it works. What I think is somehow I need to find master Form element and Controls.Add(btn) to it so it will see the event click.

Comment: I glad finally work... Right now I create empty project with one master and one content page... from content I create table and buttons and it works fine. redirecting work ok, without finding master Form. If You want I can send You example on mail.

Comment: Is it possible to put it on GitHub?

Comment: but I think is better to put <a href insted buttons (Dim a As New HtmlGenericControl("a"):a.Attributes.Add("href","https://www.google.com"):tableCellButton.Controls.Add(a)... ;) on this way you avoid creating huge viewstate value in header of page

Comment: there is dropbox link for example : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7a19e4augpxv1k1/WebApplication1.zip

Comment: Thank you for the DropBox link. This is really helpful.